# (Good Programming Practices) Two returns inside a render are correct?

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

The code below works perfectly, I would spend only knowing if this way I am doing is the most correct, because there are two instructions of return, and the second that is in the scope of the arrow function in thesis could be removed because it only returns an element , but when I do the removal, my list is not rendered.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=Vikings')
      .then((response) => {
        // handle success
        this.setState({ listaItens: response.data })
        //console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // handle error
        console.log("Erro ao recuperar dados");
      })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.listaItens.map(item => {
          return (
            <Text key={item.show.id}>{item.show.name}</Text>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two return statements are not in the same function. One of them is in the inner scope of your callback while the other one is actually returning from your render method. If you are wondering whether you should write this differently for readability's sake, I would propose the following:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.state.listaItens.map(item => <Text key={item.show.id}>{item.show.name}</Text>)}
    </View>
  );
}
```

The lamba expression allows for the return statement to be omitted if there is only one statement ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Shorter_functions)). I must mention that what you have right now is neither wrong nor bad practice.

Answer (score -2):

The second return is for `.map` array method, which is required. Since `.map` returns a new array, you have to return the elements of the original array that you  are iterating through.

Basically You could do this:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {
          [
            <Text key={this.state.listaItens[0].show.id}>{this.state.listaItens[0].show.name}</Text>,
            <Text key={this.state.listaItens[1].show.id}>{this.state.listaItens[1].show.name}</Text>,
            <Text key={this.state.listaItens[2].show.id}>{this.state.listaItens[2].show.name}</Text>,
            <Text key={this.state.listaItens[3].show.id}>{this.state.listaItens[3].show.name}</Text>
          ]
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
```